# echo -n "password"|openssl dgst -md5 -binary|openssl enc -base64

Tags: python-3.x, base64, md5, password-encryption

when I use shell command:

```
echo -n "password"|openssl dgst -md5 -binary|openssl enc -base64
```

The result is : X03MO1qnZdYdgyfeuILPmQ==

but,how can I do in python3

```
import base64, sys, hashlib
text = "password"
try:
    text = bytes(text, 'utf-8')
except:
    pass
auth = str.encode(hashlib.md5(text).hexdigest())
query = base64.b64encode(auth)
print(query)
```

The result is different：NWY0ZGNjM2I1YWE3NjVkNjFkODMyN2RlYjg4MmNmOTk=

Comment: When saving a password verifier just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Better yet use a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt`, `passlib.hash` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a substantial of time finding passwords by brute force.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are requesting the digest output in binary format when passing '-binary' option to openssl. So you have to deal with binary data in python as well. Simply use `digest()` method instead of `hexdigest()`:

```
import base64, sys, hashlib
text = "password"
try:
    text = bytes(text, 'utf-8')
except:
    pass
auth = hashlib.md5(text).digest()
query = base64.b64encode(auth)
print(query.decode())
```